# Getting image dimensions in pixels in ImageView

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, dimensions

While I try to get image dimensions in pixels in an ImageView, I found that its width is 3 times more than the original jpg file width.

I put a jpg file which dimensions are 800 x 600, but the code below displays 2400 as its width.

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imgv.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
float fwidth = bitmap.getWidth();
Log.d("width0", Float.toString(fwidth));
```

I checked the jpg file size again but it was not changed (800 x 600),
I also searched for a solution but the code above displays the correct dimensions of the bitmap on other user's experience.

What have I done incorrectly? 
Can anyone give me some advice?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `What have I done incorrectly?` Nothing. You are probably stretching your ImageView to fit the width of its container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the solution found in a web site.

I needed to change the Option value when I decode the resource not to scale the original image. I had to use the three parameters for the decodeResource function, not two.

Of course, the third parameter was Options specifying the original bitmap not to be scaled. So now I can get 800 when I call bitmap's getWidth() function.

```
                Resources res = getResources();
                int id = R.drawable.map10;
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inScaled = false;
//                options.inSampleSize = 3;
                Bitmap bb = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, id, options);

                float fwidth = bb.getWidth();
```

Comment: options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
Will give you the width without reading the whole bitmap into memory.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, that your `ImageView` is set to:
`height` : **wrap_content**
`width` : **wrap_content** 
`scaleType`: **none**

Comment: I followed your directions, wrap_content and no scale type, thanks but it is still same. Besides, I am using setImageMatrix, getImageMatrix and matrix.postScale to scale the image by fingers. Do I need to remove those codes? I am afraid that those are changing the ImageView's scale type. (like I used setScaleType())

Comment: Yes , I think if you remove then, you will get the correct image size

Comment: Then, how can I zoom in/out image inside ImageView??

Comment: I found my image is in the folder /res/drawable, can it be a problem?